# C# File Handling to get repeated Text

Tags: c#, file, file-io, file-handling

My document file consist the following data

```
Author : XXXX
Detail : abc#$

Author : YYYY
Detail : abc#$

Author : XXXX
Detail : def#$


Author : YYYYY
Detail : abc#$

Author : ZZZZZ
Detail : abc#$
```

And "`#$`" denotes the end of the detail .

```
   public  List< string>  gett(string author)
    {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("detail.doc",FileMode.Open);

        StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string data = fr.ReadToEnd();

        List<string> ff = new List<string>();


        int length = data.Length;

        for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
        {

            int i = (data.IndexOf(author, 0));

            int j = (data.IndexOf(author + "#$", 0));

            int len = j - i;


            k = j;


              ff.Add(data.Substring(i, len));

      }
         return ff;
     }
```

And i have written the above code to fetch the  detail . But something went wrong ...

And my aim is , For Example : if we give "XXXX" as author name it should  show all the "Detail" for the given author

Output like

```
 Detail:abc 
 Detail:def
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: FileStream doesn't support *doc* files, there are examples on google of how to read a doc file

Comment: What are you searching for, aka what is `au`?

Comment: Third and last: why make your own parser and not use XML based files?

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds bart ^

Comment: @BartFriederichs they fields are dynamic oly the above mentioned fields are constant

Comment: @Sayse  Its easy to read using Filestream but my question is not about  simple reading a doc file

Comment: ["Microsoft Word use a specific format for saving documents."](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5a7d4bf2-3e5d-4b23-9fe9-be0764a2cee5/reading-a-document-using-c-file-streams-and-not-using-office-pia) - I challenge you to find one working example on google of someone opening a doc file with `FileStream`

Comment: @Sayse Yes i agree ... There are lots of example but my point is how to find the repeated content as specified above ??

Comment: @BartFriederichs actually the  for loop started to be an infinite one and it add only one detail into list

Comment: @user2037787 - I *disagree*, you won't find a single example because AFAIK it cannot be done (in a usable way)

Comment: `public bool insert()
        {
            string au = "hi hello";

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("detail.doc", FileMode.Append);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

            
            sw.WriteLine(au);
            

            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();

            return true;            

        } `  this code will do the write operation in .doc file @Sayse

Comment: You can also open that "doc" file in notepad, try making a file in word and opening it in notepad, it will include a load of encoding/formatting that proves my point. The file you are creating is no more than a .txt file with .doc at the end instead of .txt. it **cant** be done

Comment: @Sayse you are correct .. Thanks .. And for the above mentioned process i  have to make my own parser and use XML file ?? else is there any other way??

Comment: look into [xml serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10y9yyta.aspx), you can load word documents but like I said, theres loads of examples on google, If your still struggling I'll try making a quick example later